# Button does nothing after being enabled on .NET Web Form

Tags: .net, webforms

A "Continue" button (we'll call it btnContinue) on a web form is either initially enabled or disabled on page load depending on the value of a Yes/No radio button (we'll call it rb1).  If the rb1 value is Yes, btnContinue is enabled, otherwise it's disabled).  If the rb1 value is "No" when the page is loaded, btnContinue is disabled.  If they subsequently change the rb1 value to "Yes", then btnContinue gets enabled, but it does nothing when clicked (i.e. it does not execute the "Navigate" method code).  The user has to save the form and reload it in order for the btnContinue code to execute when clicked.

Any suggestions?

Here's the relevant lines of code:

On the aspx page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" CssClass="myApplicationBtn"
         Text="Continue" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
         OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';"></asp:Button>
```

In the Page_Load on the aspx.cs page:

```
       if (rb1.AnswerTextValue == "Yes")
        {
            btnContinue.Enabled = true;
            btnContinue.CssClass = "myApplicationBtn";
        }
        else
        {
            btnContinue.Enabled = false;
            btnContinue.CssClass = "myApplicationBtnDisabled";
        }
```

In the btnContinue_Click method on the aspx.cs page:

```
 protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Navigate("NEXT");
 }
```

In the LoadScripts method on the aspx.cs page:

```
 foreach (ListItem item in rb1.RadioButtonList1.Items)
 {
     item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ConfirmRb1(this);");
 }
```

In the Shared.js page:

```
 function ConfirmRb1(object) {
     var button = document.getElementById("btnContinue");

     if (object.value == "No") {
         button.disabled = true;
         button.setAttribute("class", "myApplicationBtnDisabled");
     }
     else {
         button.disabled = false;
         button.setAttribute("class", "myApplicationBtn");
     }
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove that OnClientClick?

Comment: Behavior is still the same if I remove the OnClientClick event (I believe that simply prevents the user from double-clicking on the button and having the code execute multiple times).  I think the issue has to do with btnContinue being disabled via the backend on the Page_Load when the rb1 answer is No.  I'm looking to see if I can instead do the enabling/disabling of btnContinue through the front end on the aspx page and use javascript.